# Can i use async functions everywhere in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can i use async funtion inside

```
XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener('readystatechange',async function(){
```

or

```
setTimeout(async function(){
```

or

```
element.addEventListener('click',async function(){
```

Is syntax like that correct/valid?

I need await function but when i use it inside non async functions like below i got error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions"

Comment: Yes. Yes. And Yes.

Comment: The *syntax* is OK, but it's pointless unless a particular API (like, in this case, `.addEventListener()`) expects to get a Promise back from a callback function you give it. The `.addEventListener()` function doesn't know anything about Promises.

Comment: What makes you think that this is not possible? Are you facing any problems?

Comment: @Pointy `but it's pointless unless a particular API expects to get a Promise back` Or one wants to use `await` inside it.

Comment: In those three examples you can. To answer the more broad question that your title asks, the answer no. For example, using Node you can't use `async` at the top level of code.

Comment: @tkausl Yes, i want await inside function

Comment: @tkausl well that's true for a lot of cases, it can be cleaner in the function to use `await` instead of Promise callbacks. I think it's still important to be aware that "older" APIs like `setTimeout()` etc will not pay attention to the returned Promise from the `async` callback.

Answer (score 0):

All of the APIs in question expect functions which do not expect any return values. So the primary thing you gain is ability to use `await` inside the function. Which, per your comment, it seems like that's what you want. It only takes 3 minutes to test it yourself and see -

```js
setTimeout(async _ => {
  const res = await fetch(`https://httpbin.org/json`)
  const data = await res.json()
  console.log(data)
}, 1000)

console.log("loading...")
```

```
loading...
```

```js
{
  "slideshow": {
    "author": "Yours Truly",
    "date": "date of publication",
    "slides": [
      {
        "title": "Wake up to WonderWidgets!",
        "type": "all"
      },
      {
        "items": [
          "Why <em>WonderWidgets</em> are great",
          "Who <em>buys</em> WonderWidgets"
        ],
        "title": "Overview",
        "type": "all"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Sample Slide Show"
  }
}
```

But you're missing the benefit of `async` and `await` by breaking out of the promise chain by using `setTimeout` in this way. It would be much better to write a promise *around* `setTimeout` instead. Rather than punting to the event queue, this keeps data moving through the promises and allows you to sequence any asynchronous portions of your program -

```js
const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

const fetchJson = (url, opts = {}) =>
  fetch(url, opts).then(r => r.json())

async function main()
{ console.log("loading...")
  await sleep(1000)
  const data = await fetchJson(`https://httpbin.org/json`)
  console.log(data)
  return "done"
}

main().then(console.log, console.error)
```

```
loading...
```

```js
{
  "slideshow": {
    "author": "Yours Truly",
    "date": "date of publication",
    "slides": [
      {
        "title": "Wake up to WonderWidgets!",
        "type": "all"
      },
      {
        "items": [
          "Why <em>WonderWidgets</em> are great",
          "Who <em>buys</em> WonderWidgets"
        ],
        "title": "Overview",
        "type": "all"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Sample Slide Show"
  }
}
```

```
done
```

The same applies for your `addEventListner` examples